# JPA: ManyToMany Mapping Exception

Tags: jpa, mapping, many-to-many, persistence, eclipselink

I have a `ManyToMany` relation between two persistent entities `Traveller` and `Address`. Every Traveller must have 3 addresses: present, permanent and reference person address. I tried this code:

`Traveller` Entity:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "travellers")
private Address presentAdd, permanentAdd, refPersonAdd;
```

`Address` Entity:

```
@ManyToMany
private List<Traveller> travellers;
```

But this exception is shown:

```
Grave: Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer prepare 
method
Grave: Exception while preparing the app
Grave: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125- 
r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [visasMarketingPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7214] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The target entity of the relationship attribute [permanentAdd] on   
the class [class com.gis.visasmarketing.entities.Traveller] cannot be determined.  When
not using generics, ensure the target entity is defined on the relationship mapping.
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse 
Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461):  
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [visasMarketingPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7214] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 
2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The target entity of the relationship attribute [permanentAdd] on 
the class [class com.gis.visasmarketing.entities.Traveller] cannot be determined.  When
not using generics, ensure the target entity is defined on the relationship 
mapping.    
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.
predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1402)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.
createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:208)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.
loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:206)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init> 
(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:120)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:224)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.
    iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:495)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:233)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.
    prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:871)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.
    deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:410)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.
    deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.
    execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.
    doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.
    doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.
    access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext. 
    execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.
    execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.
    call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.
    service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.
    execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter
    (DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.
    execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.
    doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] 
    (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461):  
    org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
    Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit
    [visasMarketingPU] failed.
    Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7214] 
    (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461):   
    org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.
    ValidationException
    Exception Description: The target entity of the relationship attribute
    [permanentAdd] on the class [class com.gis.visasmarketing.entities.Traveller] 
    cannot  be determined.  When not using generics, ensure the target entity 
    is defined on the relationship mapping.
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.
    predeployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:221)
... 38 more
 Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7214] 
 (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461):
 org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
 Exception Description: The target entity of the relationship attribute
 [permanentAdd] on the class [class com.gis.visasmarketing.entities.Traveller] 
 cannot be determined.  When not using generics, ensure the target entity is defined 
 on the relationship mapping.
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.
 unableToDetermineTargetEntity(ValidationException.java:1959)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.
 CollectionAccessor.getReferenceClass(CollectionAccessor.java:458)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.
 ClassAccessor.addAccessor(ClassAccessor.java:277)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.
 ClassAccessor.addAccessorFields(ClassAccessor.java:415)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.
 ClassAccessor.addAccessors(ClassAccessor.java:387)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.
 ClassAccessor.preProcess(ClassAccessor.java:1134)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.
 MappedSuperclassAccessor.preProcess(MappedSuperclassAccessor.java:682)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.
 EntityAccessor.preProcess(EntityAccessor.java:554)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.
 processStage1(MetadataProject.java:1608)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProcessor.
 processORMMetadata(MetadataProcessor.java:531)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.
 processORMetadata(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:526)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.
 predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1337)
... 37 more
```

Please I need your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I defined attributes like this in my `Traveller` Entity:

```
private Address presentAdd, permanentAdd, refPersonAddTun, refPersonAddThai;
```

and in the `Address` entity:

```
private Traveller traveller;
```

Comment: So the Address has a single traveller?  If this is the 'current' traveller's presentAdd, you might want to consider using the mappedBy on one side.  Otherwise both sides have a foreign key to the other that is unnecessary and will be a pain to maintain when it changes.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define Many to Many like this. However what you are trying to do can be achieved by

Changing In your Traveller Entity;

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "travellers")
private List<Address> addresses;
```

and adding addressType (preferably Enum)  in you AddressType:

```
private AddressType type;


public Enum AddressType{
  PRESENT,PERMANENT,REFERENCE_PERSON

}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but the Address must be an entity with four attributes.